# Adding a Table to a pre-existing PDF using iTextSharp/iText

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need to add a table using iTextSharp (or even PDFSharp if it can do it) into an existing PDF template at a particular location in the template. I can edit the existing template with Adobe Designer 7.0. How can I go about doing this? Is there a PlaceHolder analog from Asp.Net which can be used here?

Keith

Answer (score 1):

After some some experimenting, yes, you can do so but with a caveat. First, put a text field down somewhere. In the code, grab the coordinates of where it is. Then build some sort of object to insert there, a table in my case. One caveat is there is no flow, the document will not adjust itself. If your object is too big, it will overwrite (overflow?) what was previously already there. I was hoping for a nice re-flow of what was there, but no dice. I finding that PDFs are a pretty static beast. But I think I'll get it to work for my needs.

Comment: Hello I have the same problem with overflowing "too big Objects" have you solved it?